# Navigation bar is hiding title and back button iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I started working on an iPhone application (XCode 5 and iOS 7). I am not sure why when I run my app, it's hiding my Navigation Bar's title and back button. Here are some screen shots.

If you look closely, something is hiding the title and back button. Not sure what?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would start by setting backgroundColor on some of the views to see if they are where you expect.

Comment: Looks okay. I tried setting the content inset as well. Still the same

Comment: Are you using a nib for your view controller? If not, how are you constructing the view?

Comment: yes, I am using storyboards

Comment: Try the visual view debugging options mentioned here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/05/visual-view-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tintcolor for the navi button

> NavController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the new `backIndicatorImage` property on `UINavigationBar` to a custom image. Also,don't forget to set the `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` as well otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try using this line of code

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO];
```

let me know.